# Custom React Hook Causing Memory Leak Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had created a custom hook to fetch data for a single item but for some reason its causing this error

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at PostPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2530:81)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48697:5)
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48630:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48110:5)
```

Here is the code

```
const useFetchMultiSingle = (mainUrl, secondaryKey, mainUrlPath, secondaryUrlPath, path) => {

    const [mainUrlDataSingle, setMainUrlDataSingle] = useState(null);
    const [secondaryUrlDataSingle, setSecondaryUrlDataSingle] = useState(null);
    const [loadingMultiUrlSingle, setLoadingMultiUrlSingle] = useState(false);
    const [errorMultiUrlSingle, setErrorMultiUrlSingle] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const apiOnePromise = axios.get(`${mainUrl}/${mainUrlPath}?secondary_id=${path}`);
        const apiTwoPromise = axios.get(`http://localhost:5555/${secondaryUrlPath}?id=${path}`);
        setLoadingMultiUrlSingle(true);
        Promise.all([apiOnePromise, apiTwoPromise])
        .then(values => {
            const response01 = values[0].data;
            const response02 = values[1].data;
            setMainUrlDataSingle(response01);
            setSecondaryUrlDataSingle(response02);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setErrorMultiUrlSingle(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoadingMultiUrlSingle(false);
        })
    }, [mainUrl, secondaryKey, mainUrlPath, secondaryUrlPath, path]);

    const refetch = () => {
        const apiOnePromise = axios.get(`${mainUrl}/${mainUrlPath}?secondary_id=${path}`);
        const apiTwoPromise = axios.get(`http://localhost:5555/${secondaryUrlPath}?id=${path}`);
        setLoadingMultiUrlSingle(true);
        Promise.all([apiOnePromise, apiTwoPromise])
        .then(values => {
            const response01 = values[0].data;
            const response02 = values[1].data;
            setMainUrlDataSingle(response01);
            setSecondaryUrlDataSingle(response02);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setErrorMultiUrlSingle(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoadingMultiUrlSingle(false);
        })
    };

  return { mainUrlDataSingle, secondaryUrlDataSingle, loadingMultiUrlSingle, errorMultiUrlSingle, refetch };
};
```

This hook fetches the data from the main url and then fetches the data from the second url based on the first api response data

Here is how i am currently calling the hook. I am just using console.log to output the api results

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useFetchMultiSingle } from '../utilities/useFetchMultiUrl';

const PostPage = () => {

    const location = useLocation();
    const path = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

    const { mainUrlDataSingle, secondaryUrlDataSingle, loadingMultiUrlSingle, errorMultiUrlSingle } = useFetchMultiSingle(process.env.REACT_APP_S_API_URL, process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY, "posts", "post", path);

    if (loadingMultiUrlSingle) return <h1>Loading</h1>

    if (mainUrlDataSingle && secondaryUrlDataSingle) console.log(mainUrlDataSingle && secondaryUrlDataSingle);

    if (errorMultiUrlSingle) console.log(errorMultiUrlSingle);

    return (
        <div>
            Single Post
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostPage;
```

Comment: This error usually appears when you try to make changes to a component that has been unmounted. So, it looks like the problem is not in your custom hook. It is in the component where you are using this hook.

Comment: @HaseebAnwar Thank you for your reply i was able to solve my own question and posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I don't know why but my problem had to do with the skeleton loading components  that were causing the problem i had initially used a single skeleton component to load in a parent if statement which then i made it conditional with each of its respective actual component it had nothing to do with the hook itself.

Here is what i initially did

```
if (isLoading) return <Skeleton/>

return (
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Component/>}/>
  <Routes>
<Router/>
)
```

And here was my fix

```
return (
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={ isLoading ? <Skeleton/> : <Component/>}/>
  <Routes>
<Router/>
)
```